# gcc: -Dvar=value not working as expected

Tags: gcc

I am trying to compile a library that has these lines:

```
#if AE_OS==AE_WINDOWS
#include windows.h
//stuff
#elif AE_OS==AE_POSIX
//other stuff
#endif
```

When I use `cpp -DAE_OS=AE_POSIX` I get

```
cpp/src/ap.cpp:63:21: fatal error: windows.h: No such file or directory
 #include <windows.h>
                     ^
```

Adding a space after the `-D` does not work, nor does putting `AE_OS=AE_POSIX` in single or double quotes, putting only `AE_POSIX` in single or double quotes, and trying all of these combinations with the quotes escaped.
Putting `AE_POSIX` in escaped single quotes at least does something different, but it is apparently still not correct:

```
cpp/src/ap.cpp:59:5: warning: character constant too long for its type [enabled by default]
 #if AE_OS==AE_WINDOWS
     ^
```

I have also tried `-D"AE_OS AE_POSIX"` thinking that would be the same as `#define "AE_OS AE_POSIX"` but apparently it ignores the quotes since it defines `AE_OS` as 1:

```
<command-line>:0:16: error: missing binary operator before token "1"
cpp/src/ap.cpp:65:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘AE_OS’
 #elif AE_OS==AE_POSIX
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preprocessor understands expressions of integer type, not strings.

AE_POSIX and AE_WINDOWS [are defined](https://github.com/dehabu/Lieopt/blob/master/alglib/ap.h) as different integers:

```
/*
 * definitions
 */
#define AE_UNKNOWN 0
#define AE_MSVC 1
#define AE_GNUC 2
#define AE_SUNC 3
#define AE_INTEL 1
#define AE_SPARC 2
#define AE_WINDOWS 1
#define AE_POSIX 2
```

So for POSIX do this:

```
cpp -DAE_OS=2
```